# unable to locate the packages slapd and slapd-utils

Tags: openldap

when trying to install `slapd` and `slapd-utils`, I receive an error message:

> unable to locate the packages .

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I ran the `update` and `upgrade` but no luck.

*How I can installs those packages?*

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to do is, update the cache:
   `apt-get update`
2. Search the package name:
   `apt-cache search slapd`
3. Install the package based on the output you see in step 2.
   `apt-get install <pakcage_name>`

However if it still not visible there must be something that need to be fix in APT.

Answer (score 0):

The package name for the OpenLDAP server is `slapd` and **not** `lapd`

```
sudo apt-get install slapd
```

and the name of the OpenLDAP utilities package is `ldap-utils` and **not** `slapd-utils`

```
sudo apt-get install ldap-utils
```